# Is it possible to use a flow to move an item from an active list to archive list based on values in certain fields and then...?

Tags: workflow, calculated-column, choice-field, copy-item, edit-update-delete

Good afternoon everyone,

I have 2 SP Lists, The first is the Active List, within this list (several columns) i have one column **"Status"** that is a choice *[New, Assigned, CM Active, Completed]* and another **"Days Open"** that is a count of days *(Calculated Column)* since the item was created.

The Second SP List has all the same columns in it but this one is for Archiving only.

Is it possible to create a flow that, when an item is updated it checks to see if the **"Status"** is *[Completed]* and the **"Days Open"** is *older than 90 Days* (>90). If both of these are true, can it then **copy that item in to the archive list** and **delete it out of the active list**. If it is false, it does nothing?

I'm relatively new to flows but a very quick learner, if somone has the time to explain it i would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried the search but its hard to nail down the question to find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Schedule/Recurrence flow to accomplish this.

1. Get the items that are older than 90 days from **Created** and having statuses **Completed** from the source list by filtering it in the Flow.
2. Loop through all the items and create new items in the destination list and then delete them from the source list.

[image]

**Expression 1**

```
Created le 'addDays(utcnow(),-90)' and Status eq 'COMPLETED'

Note: expression function, addDays(), needs to be added in the expression windows within a single quote
```

### Detail 1

[image]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thank you very much for a great answer and expertly put for a novice to understand, it works perfectly. 

Amazingly I can now see slight comparisons to flows and how i'd probably do this using VBA in Excel, very similar indeed, Filter, Copy Paste then delete selection!

Much appreciated, thank you

Steve